# Red highlighting of whitespace in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone help me understand how to get rid of this annoying red highlight before every line for all the whitespace?
The image for reference can be viewed using the link below.
The red highlighting doesn't go away unless the entire empty line is deleted.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

File > Preferences

Search for "Highlight Current Line"

And remove check mark from the check box.

Answer (score -1):

disable the extention "Highlight Trailing White Spaces"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).